# Receipt for recurring membership payment includes a link to enable cancellation. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: civimember, permissions, recurring-contributions, stripe

I'm setting up a recurring membership payment using stripe. Using the test drive page the transaction goes through fine, and I get a receipt. The receipt includes a link of the form:

https://mydomain.org/civicrm/contribute/unsubscribe?reset=1&mid=108

saying I can use this to cancel my recurring payment.

This link only seems to work if I'm logged in when I use it. Otherwise I just get taken to the front page of the site.

Should this link include a contact ID and checksum?

Drupal 9, Civi 5.49.1

Update: wondering whether it might be related to this 3 year old issue, which seems to describe something similar: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/571

Comment: It's worth noting that this problem makes it pretty difficult to fully test drive the payment workflow

Comment: I can't repro this with our Stripe Payment extension as my cancellation link looks like so: https://mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/unsubscribe&reset=1&coid=12684&cs=de576320b606ae84e93385ae395258d7_1202221350_inf (granted, we're on Joomla, Civi 5.50.1 and Stripe Pmt ext 6.7.4)

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. It's clear that your link does include a checksum, and what I assume to be a contact ID

Comment: it's the contribution ID for the last contribution in the series (the one the receipt is for)